# How to convert tiff or pnm to jpeg in Qt

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I use scanner. Ihe scanner output is in tiff or pnm format. But I cannot load these formats into QImage.

```
QProcess process;
process.start("scanimage -d epjitsu --format=tiff");
process.waitForFinished(240000);
QByteArray ba = process.readAllStandardOutput();
QImage image;
image.fromData(ba);
```

image.fromData(ba) will fail, because Qt does not know tiff format. Only way, how to convert it, is to store bytearray to file and use linux utility convert to convert it. But I do not want to go by this way. I want to do it somehow in Qt.

Comment: According to the documentation tiff is supported: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html

Comment: It might be a case where qt is configured to use system tiff support but it is not present. Which is the reason I prefer custom qt builds that bundle image formats just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I have read Qt documentation many times. But I do not to use it. What everything  I supposed to do if I want to use it on CentOS and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/index.html) to open tiff file, and them create a QImage. This QImage can be save in jpg format.

Answer (score 0):

Qt provides tiff support via libtiff.

I think the default configuration option is that it uses whatever the system provides. Which means your system should have libtiff installed.

You can also do a custom qt build where you provide the `-qt-libtiff` configuration flag, which will use the bundled lib to incorporate it into the qt binaries rather than use an external system library.

Another consideration to make is that tiff support is not in the "Qt Essentials" modules, but part of "Qt Add-Ons" in the face of the [Qt Image Formats](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimageformats-index.html) module.

Lastly, you can still resort to the option to scan to a file, then also convert the file to a supported format via an external tool.

Comment: I have to build my project with this option or I have to download Qt resources and build it wit this option?

Comment: @PeterPolak does `QImageReader::supportedImageFormats()` list tiff for you?

Comment: I see there tiff. But, if I load data from QByteArray to QImage, QImage object holds invalid picture.

Comment: The problem is not in converting tiff format to QImage but in loading QByteArray data into QImage object. If I will try QImage::fromFile(tiff file), it works.

Comment: @PeterPolak it is possible that the API cannot deduce the file format from the date alone, in which event it might be helpful to provide the specific format.

Answer (score 0):

qt knows tiff format. Following code works for me:

```
QFile f("Untitled.tiff");
if (!f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
    return;
}
QByteArray ar(f.size(), ' ');
f.read(ar.data(), ar.size());
QImage img;

img.loadFromData(ar);
if (!img.isNull())
{
    QPixmap image = QPixmap::fromImage(img);
    ui.tiffLabel->setFixedSize(img.size());
    ui.tiffLabel->setPixmap(image);
}
```

make sure you satisfy all the dll dependencies (I supect qtiff.dll)

make sure your `QByteArray ba` contains image

and, possible, is good idea to use `loadFromData` insted of `fromData`